# Tridion Audience Manager (outbound email) encrypting the PII data in contacts information like email, first name and last name

Tags: audience-manager

I am using the audience manager to create contacts for the newsletters. Actually there is a concern that the fields like email/first name and last name as getting saved in audeince manager database as the readable text which will expose this PII data related to customers to the hackers. Is there any way with which I can encrypt the values of these fields in database without effecting my outbound email. Please help by your expert advice!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that isn't possible at the moment. AM/OE support one-way encryption only. Meaning you can only use it for information that you don't want to be able to decrypt again (i.e. passwords)

Comment: Hi peter, Thanks a lot for replying. Is there any chance for getting this implemented, as email being the PII data it could be risk of these getting hacked by users

Comment: It's on the backlog, so there's a chance it will be added in the future. It's just a question of priorities.Just to be clear: do you still want the data to be visible within the UI too? So it's essentially only encrypted in the database and then decrypted whenever it is accessed?

Comment: Actually UI is having restricted access but from the website where we are calling service for creating contacts is indirectly through the service is in touch with the broker database that contains all the PII data of the users registering on the site. So there is always a possibility of getting this info hacked. That was the concern.

Comment: The AM service used on your website must also be locked down (i.e. using OAuth and restricting access by IP). Otherwise people "in the know" could indeed talk directly to it and gain access to any Contact's data. But that wasn't actually my question. I'm asking how you see it working, in a future where all of the data is encrypted: would you want it to still be displayed (unencrypted) in the CME? I assume so, but maybe you don't even want your own employees to have access to the data either.

Comment: Yes Peter we have to show the emails to the cms users in encrypted form,, actually we have given access of the CMS to only some high level managers. and they are already having access to all these details by other means.